# I cant import openCV in VSCode but i already installed the module

Tags: python, opencv, import, module

I am tring to import openCV module
[i already installed it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HykD.png)

but still i [cant use it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4M19.png)

[this is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeRHU.png) the error

and this is where my module

Requirement already satisfied: opencv-python in
c:\users\berke\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages
and

Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.19.3 in
c:\users\berke\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages

also here is the code :

```
import cv2
d = cv2.QRCodeDetector()
val, points, straight_qrcode = d.detectAndDecode(cv2.imread("qrcode.png"))
print(val)
```

its not just openCV module also i cant import all of the modules that not already inside VSCode
(I am using Python 3.10)

Comment: You almost certainly have two Python installations.  Command-line `pip` is installing in one of them, but VScode is using the other. Do `pip --version` to find out where `pip` is installing to, and compare what it reports to VScode's setting for the Python interpreter.

Comment: BoarGules is right. Use pip install in the VScode terminal.